# Is there an equivalent to EVENTDATA in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, system-tables

I am looking for ways to create a log table in my SQLite database, where I'm able to track changes that have been made. One fellow has beaten me to it [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/303805/how-to-log-changed-table-fields-in-sqlite), if someone is willing to give it a go.

Having found a [tutorial](https://jackworthen.com/2018/03/19/creating-a-log-table-to-track-changes-to-database-objects-in-sql-server/) that shows to implement a log table in T-SQL and after reading a nice guideline over [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797592/best-practice-logging-events-general-and-changes-database), I'd like to ask if there is something akin to T-SQL's `EVENTDATA()` to get what exactly is being run on the database and if there is, how to use it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, by the OP's admission, it's a dupe of [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/303805/how-to-log-changed-table-fields-in-sqlite).

Comment: AFAIK, asking if a function in T-SQL is present in another flavour is fundamentally different from asking how to implement a log table.